# Como eu defino a função push_back para uma estrutura em c++?

Tags: c++, struct

Como eu faço para poder utilizar a função `push_back` em uma estrutura?

Eu tenho a estrutura Arco:

```
struct Arco {

    int i, j;
    Arco () {};
    Arco (const Arco& obj): i(obj.i), j(obj.j) {};
    Arco(int _i, int _j) : i(_i), j(_j) {}    

};
```

E então, tenho um vetor de vetores de arcos:

```
vector < vector < Arco > > Df;

Df = vector < vector < Arco > >(nn, vector < Arco > ( ) );
```

Gostaria de poder preencher o Df da seguinte maneira:

```
Df[i][j].push_back(Arco(u,v));
```

Como devo fazer para permitir esse comando?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem apenas um vector de `vectors (2D)`.

Logo o uso correto seria este:

```
Df[i].push_back(Arco(u,v));
```

Se a sua necessidade é usar `Df[i][j].push_back(Arco(u,v));` Então, sera necessário um vector de vector de `vector (3D)`